# How to merge complex business validation with JSR-303?

Tags: java, validation, jpa, ejb, bean-validation

I'm stuck with validation in my current use case.
My app has standard structure (WEB <-> EJB3 Services <-> EJB3 DAO <-> DB).
I have an entity which has validation annotations applied to it.

```
@Entity
class PhoneNumber {

    ...

    private NumberType numberType;
}
```

where

```
enum NumberType {
    FIXED,
    MOBILE,
    ANY
}
```

Now I have new validation rule to be applied. On PhoneNumber update there should be not possible to change NumberType to ANY if it was set previously to either FIXED or MOBILE.

My Bean Validation rules are checked just before db operations, and the rule above should be applied in service layer (at least I think so) to have a DB access to get previous entity version to compare.
But without having bean not yet validated I'm forced to check manually if e.g. numberType is not null.

Can you please provide me some advices or general rules how to deal with more complex busines validations (not only checking single field's values in isolation) when using Bean Validation?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Bean Validation is the right solution for implementing this kind of business logic.

Instead you could implement this check in the `setNumberType()` method of the `PhoneNumber` entity. There you have the old value at hand and compared to an implementation in the service layer there is no chance to perform an illegal state transition by circumventing (accidentally or intentionally) the service implementing the check.

Comment: I agree to your first paragraph. But I would not put the check into the entity. In my opinion entity classes are just dumb POJOs and should not contain business logic. Otherwise you cannot thrust the business logic because in any setter could be made some implicit changes. That also makes refactoring difficult and it is hard to oversee the use case if the logic is so spread.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2010/12/putting-spell-on-bean-validation-api.html) you can find a good description of how to write a custom validator which can do "cross-field" validation.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fit to my issue. I don't need cross field validation. I need to validate one field against it's previous value (stored in DB).

Comment: So you would have to query the entity from the database in your custom validator and check against its values. But I don't think it's a good practice. Instead I would load the old entity in the business logic and check it's values here. This way you are not hiding this logic in a validator.